# SwiftUI TabView - getting number of Tabs

Tags: swiftui, tabview

Simple put, using SwiftUI to build a tabview; how can I get the numbers  ( read count ) of Tab's or tabItems of a TabView?

```
struct ContentView : View {
@State private var selection = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack{
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        Text("Stack")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                Text("Tab1")
            }.tag(0)
        Tab2()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Tab2")
            }.tag(1)
        Tab3()
    } //.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    .background(.red)
        Text("Tapped or Clicked item \(selection)")
            .font(.title)
        Button("Do something") {
            
            if selection > (tabViewCounts / 2).....
        }
        Spacer()
    }
   }
 }

struct Tab2: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Over")
    }
}

struct Tab3: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Flow")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "circle")
            Text("Tab3")
        }.tag(2)
   }
 }
```

There will be in the product a way to add or remove some tab's depending on a enum  list and actions. To avoid to keep a var to keep track of the added or removed tabView items I like to get a count somehow. I would like to read the var that keeps the number of dot's visible when in pages mode. It keep track of the hidden views
Any suggestions if this is even possible?
Thank you!

Comment: How will the tabs be added, what will be the data source for the tabs? Shouldn’t you be able to use the data source(s) in a computed property to keep track of the number of tabs.

Comment: I can do that, but still like to get a count from TabView itself. Also I use one or more packages to add a tabItem, and those doesn’t have a counterVariable to use.

Comment: Trying to work around the declarative, data-driven nature of SwiftUI in this way seems to be asking for problems.  Manage at the data source, not the view.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Anyway how can I ask the View how many child's it got?

Comment: How does the tabview knows how many dots there should be there in pages mode?